# Role based left menu in Sharepoint Services

Tags: .net, asp.net, sharepoint

I need to build a Sharepoint (Windows Sharepoint Services - WSS) site for a project management team. I built application pages(aspx) to handle some dashboard functions.

I would like to apply "security trimming" for the left menu to show the respective menu options for the user's role.

There is no OOTB functionality for this .

Can someone suggest sth ?

cheers,
gabor

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that OOTB Quick Launch cannot be audience targeted, however list items can (if you are using MOSS not just plain WSS) take a look at [this article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointserver/HA101690531033.aspx) for more details. You can than add list web part to one of the zones or even modify the page layout and publish it to left menu.

You should stick to audiences if possible, but you could also solve the problem by:

- creating a custom quick launch as a server side control
- creating a JQuery script to check permissions and update quick launch (not recommended, this is not very secure, but if you are looking just for UI adjustment and you will still be protecting your pages with OOTB SharePoint permissions it might work)

Comment: Hi Toni ! 

Unfortunately I forgot to add that  I work with WSS . This is where my issue came from since at previous client we used MOSS and that has Audience targeting. But this client has WSS . And I miss that option...

cheers,
Gabor

Comment: AFAIK then you will need to create a custom web part to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using WSS you can have a list webpart in a webpart zone strategically positioned in the menu area where the 'menu items' have specific permissions making the items only display to appropriate user, its a bit workaroundish but once setup it will become transparent.